# How to stop toggle from changing width of side nav bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When you click on the item 'Click me' in the side nav item, the whole side bar width changes if the sub navigation items are wider in size. How do I modify the code to ensure the width doesnt change as as I toggle the top level items in the side nav bar?

http://plnkr.co/edit/CE11sXlVju7zFTlg2Kr1?p=preview

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css">
<style type="text/css" media="Screen">

.icon {
position: relative;
width:1em;
height:1em;
background-color:orange;
}


.icon-minus {
position: relative;
top:0;
left:0;

}
.icon-minus:after {
background-color: #fff;
width: 8px;
height: 2px;
position: absolute;
top:7px;
left: 3.5px;
  z-index:4;
   content:"";
}

.icon-plus {
position: relative;
top:0;
left:0;
}
.icon-plus:after {
background-color: #fff;
width: 8px;
height: 2px;
position: absolute;
top:7px;
left: 4px;
  content:"";
}
.icon-plus:before {
background-color: #fff;
width: 2px;
height: 8px;
border-radius: 1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
-moz-border-radius: 1px;
position: absolute;
top:4px;
left: 7px;
  content:"";
}

 #navigation ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding:0px;
/*border:1px solid orange*/
} 
 #navigation ul li{
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-right: 1px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

/*   padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 140px; */
}

 #navigation li {
  border-right: 1px solid orange;
  border-top: 2px solid orange
  border;
}

 #navigation li li {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
#navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;

}
/*
#navigation a:active {
  padding: 2px 13px 4px 7px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

#navigation li li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 17px;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #111111;
}
#navigation li li a:active {
  padding: 2px 4px 4px 16px;
  background-color: #888;
  color: #000;
}  */
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function swap(targetId){
  if (document.getElementById){
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
            if (target.style.display == "none"){
                target.style.display = "";
            } else{
                target.style.display = "none";
            }

  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navigation" style="float:left">
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <a href="#" onclick="swap('sectionOneLinks');return false;" class="filtersNav">Click me</a>
                <ul id="sectionOneLinks" style="display: none;">
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page aaaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="swap('sectionTwoLinks');return false;">Click me</a>
                <span style="display:inline-block; float:right" class="icon icon-plus"></span>
                <ul id="sectionTwoLinks" style="display: none;">
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="swap('sectionThreeLinks');return false;">Click</a><span  style="display:inline-block; float:right" class="icon icon-minus"></span>
                <ul id="sectionThreeLinks" style="display: none;">
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <div style="float: left">
            <ul class="navigation_primary">
                <li><a href >M</a></li>
                <li><a href >M</a></li>
                <li><a href >M</a></li>
                <li><a href >M</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would you rather it do instead? You can give the parent divs a min-width. You could either set the min-widths to a constant size, or you could set the min-widths to the width of the widest child div

Comment: Give `#navigation` a width. In your example, `width:100px` would wrap the `aaaaaa` element onto a new line. If you don't want wrapping, set the width accordingly.

Comment: Isnt there someway for the parent li to inherit the width of the child ul since the child ul is already present and is not being added dynamically at run time

Comment: I like @brandon 's min width idea in the absence of anything drastically better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a fixed width to the main `ul`. Something linke this :

```
#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  width:80px;      /*Just add this property. This is an example*/
}
```

See this below :

```js
function swap(targetId) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
      target = document.getElementById(targetId);
      if (target.style.display == "none") {
        target.style.display = "";
      } else {
        target.style.display = "none";
      }

    }
  }
```

```css
.icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: orange;
}

.icon-minus {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.icon-minus:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 3.5px;
  z-index: 4;
  content: "";
}
.icon-plus {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.icon-plus:after {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 4px;
  content: "";
}
.icon-plus:before {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 7px;
  content: "";
}
#navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  width:80px;      /*Just add this property*/
}

#navigation ul li {
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-right: 1px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /*   padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 140px; */
}
#navigation li {
  border-right: 1px solid orange;
  border-top: 2px solid orange border;
}
#navigation li li {
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}
#navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation" style="float:left">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="swap('sectionOneLinks');return false;" class="filtersNav">Click me</a>
      <ul id="sectionOneLinks" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page aaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="swap('sectionTwoLinks');return false;">Click me</a>
      <span style="display:inline-block; float:right" class="icon icon-plus"></span>
      <ul id="sectionTwoLinks" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" onclick="swap('sectionThreeLinks');return false;">Click</a><span style="display:inline-block; float:right" class="icon icon-minus"></span>
      <ul id="sectionThreeLinks" style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A link to a page</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="float: left">
  <ul class="navigation_primary">
    <li><a href>M</a></li>
    <li><a href>M</a></li>
    <li><a href>M</a></li>
    <li><a href>M</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```